# Manually defining Array vs Import-CSV

Tags: powershell

Everything I read online says that import-csv creates an Array, if that were the case then these two commands create two separate arrays:

```
$file1 = @(import-csv -Path "C:\FileInfo\Fileslocal.csv") 
$file2 = @(import-csv -Path "C:\FileInfo\Files.csv")
```

Also that these two commands create arrays:

```
$a = @("Scott","Angela","Mike")
$B = @("Scott","Robert","Angela")
```

yet when I do this

```
$b | Where {$a -NotContains $_}
```

I get `Robert` as return

but when I do

```
$file2 | Where {$file1 -NotContains $_}
```

I don't get anything back.

Comment: `Import-CSV` would create an array of `[object]` where `$a` is a string array. Do you have column headers? If the column header was `Name` then `$file2 | Where {$file1.Name -NotContains $_.Name}` for example. If you do not have headers it is assuming the first row is one unless you add `-Header Name`.. again for example. You are comparing apples with slightly different apples with an important difference.

Comment: There is more to potentially explain but we don't see the data in either of your files so I am just covering a few avenues.

Comment: Actually I am running the script with the one fix of adding column name and that appears to resolve the issue

Comment: you may want to add that as an actual answer so you can get credit for it. I know you just saved me a ton of time and the last few hairs I have on my head

Comment: FYI `Get-Content C:\folder\file.txt` would create a single dimension array (one entry per line in file) similar to `@("Scott","Angela","Mike")`.

Comment: @JamesC. Assuming there was no header and the file was just a single "column"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the contents of your files but from comments and assumption we are going to say they contain a list of file names with a column header. So looking at your two data types that you are comparing..

We have your string arrays `$a` and `$b` which you defined. Then you have `$file1` and `$file1` which [Import-CSV](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) made. Looking at MSDN `Import-CSV`...

> Creates table-like **custom objects** from the items in a CSV file.

While they share similar properties they are actually different types of objects. If you looked at the members of `$file1` with `Get-Member` you would see a NoteProperty for every column.

Now coming to your code

> ```
> $file2 | Where {$file1 -NotContains $_}
> ```

I would have expected you to get *something* back albeit not what you wanted. If you are comparing columns in CSV objects you should use the *column names* in your logic.

```
$file2 | Where {$file1.Name -NotContains $_.Name}
```

That would return all of the "rows" in `$file2` where the `name` in $file2 is not in the list of `name`s in `$file1`

---

Without going into too much detail this type of comparison logic has other options.

- Just read them in with `Get-Content` and skip the first line if it has a header with `Select-Object -Skip 1`
- Consider `Compare-Object`. While it is considered a performance hog it should work perfectly fine for smaller datasets.
- Import the lists as hashtables which opens up more comparison options which are performance friendly but might not *appear* as simple.